# Long boot time for Jhipster & Stripe

Tags: spring-boot, stripe-payments, jhipster

I am facing a strange boot time issue. I have the latest version of Jhipster (6.8.0) alongside the latest Stripe Java (19.10.0).

The time the system takes to boot varies between 6-10 minutes on average after adding the Stripe library, where as if you put the Stripe library on a fresh spring boot installation it loads in less than 10 seconds.

I was wondering if anyone has had the same issue, on potentially which library is causing this disturbance at the boot time and how to solve it.

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds very odd that it takes 6-10 minutes. Is that just with the library included or are you calling any setup code or API calls?

Comment: Yes its just simply a fresh installation of Jhipster with Stripe library, nothing else. I setup another parallel setup with simply starter-web and stripe, booted at around 5 second. Tried debugging it at boot and I couldn't see anything that could be slowing it down. Mind you it boots fine, but takes 6-10 minutes on average.

Comment: And if you remove Stripe how long does it take to boot without Stripe?

Comment: Around 10-12 seconds.

Comment: Are you able to see what the process is doing while it's starting up? Is there some sort of verbose output you can use when starting?

Comment: Yes, opened all the logs, all going through as normal, no errors, no warnings, so I've  resorted to the process of elimination right now to see if I can get to the bottom of this strange issue.

Comment: @cjav_dev

So, fixed the issue. The issue lied on the ResponseEntity return type, technically you cant use the Stripe class as a return type, so it should be used on its own and without a type, but in order to ensure return type complies with the Stripe model, you could use the Json value and map it to the target Class before returning it.